# Редактирование текстур модели сделанной в Metahuman Creator

Tags: unreal-engine-4, текстура

Решил попробовать сделать небольшую игрушку-платформер на UE4, модели людей для которых буду брать из Metahuman Creator. Беру там, потому что хочется реалистичности)

Сам вопрос: как достать из МХК текстуры человека, для дальнейшего редактирования (например сделать другой оттенок кожи - красный)? Функционал там очень скудный, и сделать нужный результат - нереально.